# how to use if condition in webgrid using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I am trying to display the link based on if condition in web grid in asp.net mvc.
If the record exceeds end date, then the link is displayed else not.

```
grid.Column("", format: (item =>
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > item.EndDate)
        {
            Html.ActionLink(
                "File ClAIM",
                "Edit",
                new { id = item.id },
                new { @class = "action-link" });
        }
        return false;
    }))
```

It is displaying false in all my records.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) following way:

```
grid.Column("", format: (item => { DateTime.Now > item.EndDate ? Html.ActionLink("File ClAIM", "Edit", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "action-link" }) : String.Empty }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` before `Html.ActionLink(...)`. Since the `return false` is not in an `else` branch it is executed in either case. I added a bit of formatting to your code snippet. My point might be a bit more obvious to you this way.

By the way, `false` is not a string. I am slightly surprised that the code compiles, though I don't know the webgrid component in detail. You will want to return a string in the else case, too. `string.Empty`, `null`, `"&nbsp;"` - whatever you see fit.